# Restore from snapshot failed for node group in replication group test-cache. Failed to retrieve file from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis-cluster, elastic-cache

I am trying to migrate my elastic cache from aws region: `us-east-1` to `ap-south-1`. I took snapshot of my source elastic cache, copied to s3 bucket, created a new s3 bucket in Mumbai region and added ACL permissions (canonical id) and trying to restore but failed due to error:

> Restore from snapshot failed for node group 0001 in replication group
> test-cache. Failed to retrieve file from S3

I added ACL permissions to S3 bucket and also canonical id.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to s3 and open the rdb file where it is located.
2. Go to the permissions tab and click *edit* and add Grantee
   540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353
   with check all(read, write) option.
   Save it and try again.